# Waiting for the PDF printer to finish, PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a PowerBuilder app that creates informs and save then as PDF with PDFCreator. After that, I want to send those files by mail, using an stored procedure in SQL server 2008.

For example, I have 50 informs. I want to:
- Save all to pdf (50 pdf files - PowerBuilder app)
- Send them by mail (stored procedure - SQL)

I save every inform with a DataWindow (.saveAs method):
dw_1.saveAs(ls_path, PDF!, true)

If I try to run the app and, after that, run the stored procedure, the saving-to-pdf-process is much slower than the execution time of the app, so I cannot send the files by mail, because they have not been created yet... :(

What can I do? Any ideas?

Thx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Caveat: Haven't tried this myself.*

I would expect that if you tried to FileOpen() the created PDF with LockReadWrite!, it would fail if the PDF creation process hadn't finished. So, I would try a loop with a Sleep() in it, exiting when the FileOpen() had succeeded. (Remember to FileClose() on success!) Call the stored proc after the loop exits.

Good luck,

Terry.

Answer (score 0):

We use the DataWindow saveas PDF (Ghostscript) which does not return until the PDF is created.

Comment: Which saveas method? In Sybase docs there are two 'saveas', but none of them says that does not return until the PDF is created... thx

Comment: One is for DataWindows, and one is for Graph controls inside DataWindows. I was referring to SaveAs for the DataWindow, but I'd expect the version for Graphs to behave the same way. I've looked at the SaveAs several times in Process Explorer and I can assure you PB starts Ghostscript and waits until it exits.

Comment: Maybe you could start the process and open a response window at the same time, polling for completion. I haven't had a lot of luck with the PB PDF creation but some have. Many companies already have solutions in place especially Fortune 500 if you ask around in your IT Dept. maybe there is a folder you can drop a file and have it automatically turned into PDF. :)